# Using shell to apply program to thousand of files

Tags: shell

I have never used shell scripts until now so I'm having trouble doing what I want. I have about 5000 fits files on which I would like to apply a program called Spexxy.

The program, Spexxy, has to be called in the terminal like this:

```
Spexxy config.yaml file.fits
```

With `config.yaml` the configurations to apply to the fits file.

The big issue is that I have to apply this program to my ~5000 files but for each fits file there is a specific config.yaml file.

How can I realize this ? Thanks

EDIT:
So to answer the few first comment, each `config.yaml` file is named after the spectra (fits file) it is applied to, for example:

```
ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f000.fits
ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f000.yaml
```

All those file are located in the same directory, to make it easier.

Also, indeed Spexxy can be applied to many fits files at once with one configuration yaml file but I have no use for this in this case as for each fits correspond only one yaml file.

I have not yet started writing my code as I am checking how to do this in shell and I am new with this, if you have some advice it would be welcome !

Comment: How do we distinguish one `config.yaml` from another `config.yaml` to determine which goes with which file? Are the files you have to apply `Spexxy` to all located in the same directory? If not, where? You need to provide enough information so we do not have to guess to try and solve your problem. A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be provided, but I understand if you are just starting, that may not be possible, but you need to provide at minimum, the details that would allow us to help you arrive at one. Please edit and provide the necessary details.

Comment: When we don't have any logic how to specify the right `config.yaml` for each file, a readonable answer is making a script with ~5000 lines, each line with one `Speccy some.yaml somefile.fits`. You can extract `Speccy` from this file (using a loop or `xargs`), but I hop there is some other way to specify files and yammels.

Comment: Note that `spexxy` can process multiple fits file with the same config.yaml. If you have few config files, consider `spexxy config1.yaml file1.fits file2.fits file3.filts ...`, for each config file..

Comment: Indeed i've just been started so I admit it may not be clear enough for now, I'll edit this tomorrow to explain better how this is happening, thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a job for **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel spexxy {.}.yaml {} ::: *fits
```

As regards syntax, all you need to know for this is:

- `{}`  is a placeholder for the current file
- `{.}` is a placeholder for the current file without its extension

If you want to see what it would do, without doing anything, add `--dry-run` like this:

```
parallel --dry-run spexxy {.}.yaml {} ::: *fits
```

**Sample Output**

```
spexxy ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f000.yaml ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f000.fits
spexxy ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f001.yaml ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f001.fits
spexxy ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f003.yaml ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f003.fits
spexxy ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f004.yaml ngc6397id000000002jd2456871p6250f004.fits
```

If that looks correct, remove `--dry-run` and run it for real. You can also add other things, like:

- `parallel --eta ...`   which gives you an *"Estimated Time of Arrival"*
- `parallel --bar ...`   which gives you a progress bar
- `parallel -j 8  ...`   which runs 8 jobs at a time rather than the default of 1 job per CPU core

Note also that **GNU Parallel** can distribute work across other machines in your network, and it has fail and retry handling, output tagging and so on...

If your file list is too long, you can feed the filenames in like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*fits -print0 | parallel -0 spexxy {.}.yaml {}
```

Answer (score 0):

- With `find` List all files with .fits extension from a current directory
- With `sed` remove extensions
- With `xargs` run the command for each file

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.yaml' -type f |
sed 's/\.yaml$//' |
xargs -I{} spexxy {}.yaml {}.fits
```

Comment: Surely you want `xargs -P 8` or somesuch?